# How to trigger the Kubernetes deployment restart on configmap change in subchart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have an external base-helm-chart where I'd like to define in `deployment.yaml`:

```yaml
spec:
  tempalte:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ .Files.Glob "config/*" }}
```

Where my configuration files are located in **each subchart projects** and I want the deploy to be restarted when **they are changed**:

```
/my-service:
  /config: HERE
    application.properties
    application-kubernetes.yaml #yes I'm from the Spring stack
  /helm:
    /config: OR HERE
    chart.yaml
```

But it doesn't work because files are relative, i.e. it only searches in the base-helm-chart directory.

I could *override* the `deployment.yaml` on subchart side but [it's not possible](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files) either as I understood. I have to rewrite that which is not convenient.

**Q:** How I extend the parent `deployment.yaml` template in subchart with another template to put there `{{ .Files.Glob "config/*" }}`?

The **workaround** I have is to use `values` and to calculate the sha outside of helm:

base-helm-chart `deployment.yaml`

```yaml
spec:
  tempalte:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        configHash: {{ .Values.configMap.configHash }}
```

Where in the subchart I have in `values`:

```yaml
my-service:
  configMap:
    configHash: ${CONFIG_HASH} #e.g. 27b0b9b6a41e3e752aa0b36532887cd9d946d2660c6cd58e31b6eb083ad6a8cb
```

Where `$CONFIG_HASH` comes from outside. But this solution is not cohesive, I'd like to rely on helm native mechanism as I think it should be possible.

---

**Q:** Is there another better solution?

Comment: Have you tried something like this? https://sanderknape.com/2019/03/kubernetes-helm-configmaps-changes-deployments/

Other options are: 1) use Kustomize instead of Helm (specifically, use a configMapGenerator to dynamically prefix configmap names with a hash); 2) use Reloader https://github.com/stakater/Reloader

Comment: @karl in the article example relevant for one hell case, I need to apply for for subcharts, with the configuration in subchart project